# Negative scroll to the left

Tags: javascript, css, sharepoint

All I am trying to do is have a scroll bar that allows me to navigate to the left on a SharePoint site. I tried a couple examples that I found online using CSS and javascript, but It seems i don't know enough to make it  with just one scroll and to make it appear on say -120pixels.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

When I reach the edge the scroll appears.

[image]

Thank You for reading.

Comment: Adding a jsfiddle with some working code illustrating your problem will make finding a solution easier.

Comment: It is most likely that you are not seeing any scrollbar is because the elements are floating and parent elements do not expand farther than the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to add your code and/or a working example.** Otherwise, it's tough to determine the source of your problem.

---

You can always force a scroll bar via the CSS `overflow` definition.

```
overflow: scroll;
```

[The MDN `overflow` page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow) provides a good explanation and demo of each option. It's states the following for `scroll`:

> `scroll`
>
> The content is clipped and desktop browsers use scrollbars,
>   whether or not any content is clipped. This avoids any problem with
>   scrollbars appearing and disappearing in a dynamic environment.
>   Printers may print overflowing content.

You can specify the direction if necessary, though the MDN page warns of possible compatibility issues. I'm unaware of any issues.

```
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Answer (score -1):

This sounds as though an issue with float, overflow and the s4-workspace primary container div. Very difficult to explain further though without more code and larger screenshots. Or a screenshot with Firebug loaded so that we can see what containers exist and what css is appied to them.